# Git не игнорирует файл из .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Каким образом можно сделать что бы при git pull гит игнорировал один файл из репозитория? Сам файл я добавил в .gitignore, но при git pull выдает ошибку:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>          config/secrets.yml
>   Please move or remove them before you can merge.
>   Aborting

Дело в том, что этот файл содержит пароли, и нельзя его хранить в открытом доступе.

Answer (score 5):

Проблема заключается в том, что `.gitignore` игнорирует только те файлы, которые не были добавлены ранее (через `git add`).

1. Вам необходимо проверить, что в файле `.gitignore` у Вас содержится запись 
   о игнорируемом файле.
2. Выполнить команду  `git rm --cached /config/secrets.yml`

> Полезная штука, которую вы можете захотеть сделать — это удалить файл
>   из индекса, оставив его при этом в рабочем каталоге. Другими словами,
>   вы можете захотеть оставить файл на винчестере, и убрать его из-под
>   бдительного ока Git'а. Это особенно полезно, если вы забыли добавить
>   что-то в файл `.gitignore` и по ошибке проиндексировали, например,
>   большой файл с логами, или кучу промежуточных файлов компиляции. Чтобы
>   сделать это, используйте опцию [`--cached`](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2):

Полезная ссылка: [Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7528016/5275890)

Comment: Слова «полезная штука» делают перевод душевнее. ))

Comment: Для файлов настроек лучше использовать не ignore, а залить в репозиторий эталонный файл, и на рабочих копиях сделать `git update-index --skip-worktree /config/secrets.yml`